# Issue with DT library edit data fields

Tags: r, dt

Running this code from R Studio giving the following Error.

Code -

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
DT::datatable(head(iris), editable = 'cell')
```

### Error -

> DT::datatable(head(iris), editable = 'cell')
>   Error in DT::datatable(head(iris), editable = "cell") : 
>   unused argument (editable = "cell")

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
DT::datatable(head(iris), editable = 'cell')
```

the output result data values should be editable.

```
Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width Petal.Length    Petal.Width Species
1   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
2   4.9 3   1.4 0.2 setosa
3   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4   4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
5   5   3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
6   5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
7   4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3 setosa
8   5   3.4 1.5 0.2 setosa
9   4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2 setosa
10  4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 setosa
```

Comment: What is your version of DT ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What version of  `DT` are you using?

Comment: [When in doubt, try to update your packages.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/)

Comment: When I installed it from my R studio ( install.packages("DT", dependencies = T ) version it shows 0.2 under user libraries.

Comment: We are using DT version 0.2 on R platform version 3.4.3.   We tried to install latest version of DT 0.6 on our current version of R platform. Now the question is Does this latest version of DT 0.6 supports on R studio platform 3.4.3 ? Is there a workaround ?   and out underlying runtime is microsoft machine learning server.